# What kind of fish is this white blue-stained fish?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, ichthyology, marine-biology

[image]
This fish has been spotted at the Great Barrier Reef near Cairns (Queensland).
I put a big effort to find it via Google but never could encounter anything similar.

I have also made an attempt to find this fish [here](https://fish.ala.org.au/taxon/species?key=53badad1bc521e948953e1ab7b6d79ba) with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether this helps, but that looks like a parrot fish.  I had a look online and also didn't find anything with that distinctive pattern. The closest I could find was *[Scarus ghobban](https://www.fishbase.se/summary/5548)* (common names include [blue-barred and blue-trim parrotfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarus_ghobban)), which is highly variable but the blue edges on the fins seem constant.

According to the sources linked above this fish can be seen in areas with sandy bottoms, so that seems consistent with your photograph.

[Reference pictures](https://www.reeflifesurvey.com/species/scarus-ghobban/):
[image: From: reeflifesurvey.com — Scarus ghobban, Female, WA, Australia, Photo: Graham Edgar]
[image: From: reeflifesurvey.com — Scarus ghobban, Female, Jervis Bay, NSW, Photo: Andrew Green]
[image: Scarus ghobban, male — from: Randall, J.E., 1997. Randall's underwater photos. Collection of almost 2,000 underwater photos (slides). Unpublished.]